# How to print dates between two dates in format %Y%m%d in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, date

I have two arguments as inputs:  `startdate=20160512` and `enddate=20160514`.

I want to be able to generate the days between those two dates in my bash script, not including the startdate, but including the enddate:

20160513
20160514
I am using linux machine.
How do I accomplish this?  Thanks.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/141166/20629

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Using GNU date:

```
$ d=; n=0; until [ "$d" = "$enddate" ]; do ((n++)); d=$(date -d "$startdate + $n days" +%Y%m%d); echo $d; done
20160513
20160514
```

Or, spread over multiple lines:

```
startdate=20160512
enddate=20160514
d=
n=0
until [ "$d" = "$enddate" ]
do  
    ((n++))
    d=$(date -d "$startdate + $n days" +%Y%m%d)
    echo $d
done
```

#### How it works

- `d=; n=0`

  Initialize variables.
- `until [ "$d" = "$enddate" ]; do`

  Start a loop that ends on `enddate`.
- `((n++))`

  Increment the day counter.
- `d=$(date -d "$startdate + $n days" +%Y%m%d)`

  Compute the date for `n` days after `startdate`.
- `echo $d`

  Display the date.
- `done`

  Signal the end of the loop.

Comment: using gnu date you can simplify like this: `d=$(date --date="$startdate +$n days")`

Comment: @LarsFischer Very good.  Answer updated to use English instead of math.

Comment: Hmmm.  thank you for the awesomely detailed explanation.  For posterity:  THIS DOES NOT WORK ON A MAC.

Comment: Yes, unless customized, Macs use BSD utilities, not GNU utilities.  The very nice `-d` option used here is GNU only. (In the future, you may want to add an OSX tag to your Mac questions.)

Comment: Nice one. Used it to find which dated files were missing in a directory: `startdate=20180823 ; enddate=20191031 ; d= ; n=0 ; until [ "$d" = "$enddate" ]; do       ((n++));     d=$(date -d "$startdate + $n days" +%Y%m%d);      f=app.log-$d.gz ; test -f $f || echo $f ; done`.

Answer (score 3):

This should work on OSX, make sure your startdate is lesser than enddate, other wise try with epoch.

```
startdate=20160512
enddate=20160514

loop_date=$startdate

let j=0
while [ "$loop_date" -ne "$enddate" ]; do
        loop_date=`date   -j -v+${j}d  -f "%Y%m%d" "$startdate" +"%Y%m%d"`
        echo $loop_date
        let j=j+1
done
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use `dateseq` from `dateutils` (http://www.fresse.org/dateutils/#dateseq). `-i` changes the input format and `-f` changes the output format.

```
$ dateseq -i%Y%m%d -f%Y%m%d 20160512 20160514
20160512
20160513
20160514
$ dateseq 2016-05-12 2016-05-14
2016-05-12
2016-05-13
2016-05-14
```